# Should I normalize a 1.3 million record flat file for analysis?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, normalization

I've been handed an immense flat file of health insurance claims data.  It contains 1.3 million rows and 154 columns.  I need to do a bunch of different analyses on these data.  This will be in SQL Server 2012.

The file has 25 columns for diagnosis codes (`DIAG_CD01`
 through `DIAG_CD_25`), 8 for billing codes (`ICD_CD1` through `ICD_CD8`), and 4 for procedure modifier codes (`MODR_CD1` through `MODR_CD4`).  It looks like it was dumped from a relational database.  The billing and diagnosis codes are going to be the basis for much of the analysis.

So my question is whether I should split the file into a mock relational database.  Writing analysis queries on a table like this will be a nightmare.  If I split it into a parent table and three child tables (`Diagnoses`, `Modifiers`, and `Bill_codes`) my query code will much easier.  But if I do that I'll have, on top of the 1.3 million parent records, up to 32.5 million diagnosis records, up to 10.4 million billing code records, and up to 5.2 million modifier records.  On the other hand, a huge portion of the flat data of the three sets is null fields, which are supposed to screw up query performance.

What are the likely performance consequences of querying these data as a mock relational database vs. as the giant flat file?  Reading about normalization it sounds like performance should be better, but the sheer number of records in a four table split gives me pause.

Comment: Denormalized data is a lot easier to analyze. Normalization is used to avoid update anomalies but it sounds like this data is static

Comment: AFAIK denormalized is easier for life. And if performance is important, don't do it in SQL. If you load the data to local RAM and write your code in plain C or some "classic" programming language, you can use various advanced data structures and achieve unparalled speed.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan yeah, it's static.  I'd like to avoid queries with 24 `or` lines though

Comment: @Rominus - exactly.  Put all diagnosis codes in one table, so that you don't have to write queries against 25 columns separately and somehow aggregate them together.  If you have a decent machine these row counts should not be a performance problem for sql server.

Comment: @SlimsGhost that is exactly what I was planning; sounds like I don't need to worry about SQL Server choking on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like if you keep it denormalized you would have to repeat query logic a whole bunch of times (25 for Diagnoses), and even worse, you have to somehow aggregate all those pieces together.

Do like you suggested and split the data into logical tables like Diagnosis Codes, Billing Codes, etc. and your queries will be much easier to handle.

If you have a decent machine these row counts should not be a performance problem for sql server.  Just make sure you have indexes to help with your joins, etc.

Good luck!